# Looping through dates until a free one is found

Tags: php

I have a function which checks my database to see if a date exists, if it does exist, i want to display the next date which isnt in the database.

Is this possible?

My function returns 1 if there is a date in the database and 0 if there isnt, im using codeigniter, but not using any built in functions.

Its basically an availability checker, it allows us to input many different dates in the database, so calling my function i use

```
$availcheck = $ci->availability->check_availability_by_date(date('d/m/Y'));
```

The i use a if statement to check if the first time it runs it returns a value, this is how i have it

```
if($availcheck > 0){
    // loop through the next dates and run the function again to see if it returns 0
} else {
    echo 'available now';
}
```

I guess i would add 1 to the current date, check that one, then add another 1 and check that and so on.

Im just not sure how.

Cheers,

Comment: Do you have direct access to the database, probably easier to find the next hole in the date column from a specified date.

Comment: You need to define a starting date and an ending date to check between them to avoid the risk of going to outer space..

Comment: I dont have direct access ... I need it to be done by code :(

Comment: @ gustyaquino .... Thats an interesting point, the start date would be the date after 'today' but an end date would be hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you correct , your problem is adding the day ? 
if so i would suggest using the epoch or [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)
so convert the date to unix time using [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) than just add 1 day in seconds (24*60*60)
and then convert back to d/m/y format.
you can use the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
$date = time();  // get current timestamp
while ($availcheck)  // while date IS found in database
{
$availcheck = $ci->availability->check_availability_by_date(date('d/m/Y',$date));
$date = $date + (24*60*60);  // add one day
}
$date = $date - (24*60*60);  // reduce one day
echo date('d/m/Y',$date);  // prints the first date that is not in the DB
```

Comment: That bit isnt too bad ... the bit im stuck on is looping day by day until it doesnt exist in the database.

Comment: @Cecil: This does that.  On completion, `$oldDate` will be the next available.  Set `$day,$month,$year` appropriately before entering this code.

Comment: @yossi: What you had before was fine.  Though you know you can do `mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day + 1, $year)` and it'll sort it out.

Comment: You keep mentioning looping, but if you only need one result (such as the next available date) then just query for the next row in the database that is greater than today and 'date = 0000-00-00'.

Comment: but he want to find the next date that is NOT is the database

Comment: Ok, what im trying to achieve is like the following: get todays date, check to see if that exists in the database, if it does, add one day to the previous day and check if that exists in the database, if that does, add one day to the previous and check again ... once it doesnt find a result in the database, then stop searching and print out the date which it didnt find

Comment: well , i edited it a bit and i think this is exactly what you are looking for, hope this helps.

Comment: Thats perfect ... Except it echos out one day ahead of what it finds

Comment: It displays one day ahead of what its meant to though ... should i put echo date('d/m/Y,$date - (24*60*60)); at the end to get the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

This SQL code could work for me.
    $today = date("Y-m-d"); //today

```
$sql = "SELECT date FROM calendar WHERE date>'{$today}' AND date<='2100-12-31' AND date='0000-00-00' LIMIT 1";
```

Since you can't determine the ending date, 2100 could be for testing.

Comment: That would mean that you need to know the date in the database before running the query yes?

Comment: Edited for the start date to be tomorrow